# How many onto functions are there from a set $|T|=n+1$ to a set $|S|=n$?

Tags: functions

How many onto functions are there from a set $|T|=n+1$ to a set $|S|=n$?

It is well known that the number of onto functions from $|T|=m$ to $|S|=n$ is given by $$  n!\left(m\brace n\right)$$ where $m\brace n$ denotes a Sterling number of the second kind.

However, when $m=n+1$, I suppose the the computation may be simpler and not require this formula.

Thus we want to prove the number of surjections from $T\to S$, with $|T|=n+1$ and $|S|=n$ is $$\frac{n(n+1)!}{2}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\cdot n!=(1+...+n)n~!$$

Consider the simpler case from here by momentarily letting $T^*=T\setminus\{n+1\}$. Thus, $|T^*|=n$.

We find the number of onto functions from $T^*\to S$. From here it is easy to see that there are $n!$ such functions since the first element of $T^*$ has a choice of $n$ elements to map to in $S$, then the second element in $T$ of has a choice of $n-1$ elements to map to in $S$, ... , and so on. Thus there are $$n\cdot(n-1)\cdot(n-2)\cdot...\cdot1=n!$$

such surjections.

Consider $T^*\cup\{n+1\}=T\therefore|T^*\cup\{n+1\}|=n+1$.

Since there are $n!$ onto functions that map $\{1,...,n\}\to\{1,...,n\}$, an onto map from $\{1,...,n,n+1\}\to\{1,...,n\}$ must map two $n_T\in\{1,...,n,n+1\}$ into the same element in $\{1,...,n\}$, thus there are at least $$n\cdot n!$$ such onto functions now.

Here is where I am stuck. How do I count what that last added element adds to the number of surjections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An onto function from a set with $n+1$ elements to a set with $n$ elements will necessarily have $2$ elements from the domain mapping to the same element in the codomain and then all remaining elements in the domain mapping to a unique element in the codomain.

- Pick which two elements from the domain share an output
- Pick what that output was
- From smallest to largest, pick what the output is for each remaining element

The number of such functions is then:

$$\binom{n+1}{2}n(n-1)! = (n+1)!\cdot \frac{n}{2}$$

Comment: @coreyman317 we apply the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) which paraphrased means that if we can describe each outcome via a sequence of choices such that the number of options per choice doesn't depend on previously made choices (even if the available choices themselves can change), then the total number of outcomes is the product of the number of choices.  Here specifically we have $\binom{n+1}{2}$ ways of picking which two elements from the domain share an output.  The binomial coefficient counting the number of subsets of a given size from a given set...

Comment: ... As for the factorial, this is just repeated application of the rule of product.  There were $n-1$ remaining options for the output of the smallest remaining element from the domain since it can't share an output with the pair picked earlier.  There are $n-2$ options for the output of the second smallest remaining element since it can't match either of these., and so on... giving $(n-1)\times (n-2)\times \cdots$